# React-Native: Go back on android hardware back button pressed

Tags: android, reactjs, webview, react-native

I am trying to add going back on webview when the android backbutton was pressed and I still couldn't manage to make it work.

This is my code:

```
<WebView
    ref={WEBVIEW_REF}
    source={source}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
/>

componentDidMount() {
    BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
        if(this.state.backButtonEnabled) {
            this.refs[WEBVIEW_REF].goBack();
            return true;
        }
    });
};

onNavigationStateChange = (navState) => {
    this.setState({
        backButtonEnabled: navState.canGoBack,
    });
};
```

With the code above I'm getting the error undefined is not an object this.state.backButtonEnabled (which is set in the state).

Than I just wanted to see if the goBack works so I removed the if statement and than I was getting the error undefined is not an object this.refs[WEBVIEW_REF].

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: what if you throw the backandroid event listener in the render method?

Comment: I am getting the same errors.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    state = {};
    componentDidMount(){
         BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backHandler);
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
         BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backHandler);
    }
    backHandler = () => {
        if(this.state.backButtonEnabled) {
            this.refs[WEBVIEW_REF].goBack();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

1) Bind your handler 2) Do not forget to removeListener on unmount.

Comment: I did managed to fix it 5 minutes ago and this was actually the thing I did also :) Thanks for help still, I'm sure will help also other developers!

Comment: BackAndroid will be deprecated it's better to use BackHandler like @RamRovi answered

Answer (score 47):

Wanted to add a full example in case it helps anyone:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BackHandler,
  Platform,
  WebView,
} from 'react-native';

class ExampleWebView extends Component {
  webView = {
    canGoBack: false,
    ref: null,
  }

  onAndroidBackPress = () => {
    if (this.webView.canGoBack && this.webView.ref) {
      this.webView.ref.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onAndroidBackPress);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: "https://www.google.com" }}
        ref={(webView) => { this.webView.ref = webView; }}
        onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => { this.webView.canGoBack = navState.canGoBack; }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a comprehensive solution. You should create a gist perhaps?

Comment: Getting error - TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.webView.ref = webView')

Comment: Need to bind `onAndroidBackPress` I think?

Comment: @Crisfole not if you use arrow functions like i have in the example here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are some added complexities, particularly when it comes to event binding. I could be wrong though. https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2015/11/02/of-classes-and-arrow-functions-a-cautionary-tale/

Comment: Looks like `canGoBack` is always set to `false` if the webpage uses js navigation, and doesn't do a full page reload.

Comment: 100% work for me all cases and all screens in webview

Answer (score 14):

Here's a solution with Typescript and `useRef` and `useEffect` hooks.

I didn't use `canGoBack`, but it seems to work regardless.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

const WebViewWrapper = (): JSX.Element => {
  const webview = useRef<WebView>(null);
  const onAndroidBackPress = (): boolean => {
    if (webview.current) {
      webview.current.goBack();
      return true; // prevent default behavior (exit app)
    }
    return false;
  };
  useEffect((): (() => void) => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onAndroidBackPress);
    return (): void => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onAndroidBackPress);
    };
  }, []); // Never re-run this effect
  return (
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: 'https://stackoverflow.com' }}
      ref={webview}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: This line helped me `return true; // prevent default behavior (exit app)`.

Answer (score 9):

This might help someone as the above solutions didn't solve my problem....

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BackHandler,
  WebView,
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.WEBVIEW_REF = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
}

handleBackButton = ()=>{
   this.WEBVIEW_REF.current.goBack();
   return true;
}

onNavigationStateChange(navState) {
  this.setState({
    canGoBack: navState.canGoBack
  });
}

render(){
   return (
    <WebView
        source={{ uri: "https://www.cbt.ng" }}
        ref={this.WEBVIEW_REF}
        onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
     />
    )

 }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for a `functional component` solution.

> Note: canGoBack state is not required for performing back operation, it's just to save the current state, you can safely remove it if you want

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import { BackHandler, Platform } from "react-native"
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-navigation"
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview"

const Webview = () => {
  const webView = useRef(null);
  const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', HandleBackPressed);

      return () => {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', HandleBackPressed);
      }
    }
  }, []); // INITIALIZE ONLY ONCE

  const HandleBackPressed = () => {
    if (webView.current) {
      webView.current.goBack();
      return true; // PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR (EXITING THE APP)
    }
    return false;
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <WebView
        ref={webView}
        source={{
          uri: "<YOUR_URL>"
        }}
        onNavigationStateChange={navState => setCanGoBack(navState.canGoBack)}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default Webview;
```

Comment: Please don't use a state for maintaining canGoBack, because on change of which would cause a re-render, instead use refs

Comment: Hey this is working but from the app wecannot exit on pressing backbutton like from home we pressed back so it should be exit but its not exiting the app

Comment: it will not exit the app till the history length is not less than 2

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `onNavigationStateChange` does not get triggered for SPA (single page application) sites: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1510

Use `onLoadProgress` instead:

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { BackHandler } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

export default function App() {
  const webView = useRef();

  const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = useState(false);

  const handleBack = useCallback(() => {
    if (canGoBack && webView.current) {
      webView.current.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }, [canGoBack]);

  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handleBack);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handleBack);
    };
  }, [handleBack]);

  return (
    <WebView
      ref={webView}
      source={{ uri: "https://my-awesome-spa.com/" }}
      onLoadProgress={(event) => setCanGoBack(event.nativeEvent.canGoBack)}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Nisharg Shah Answer. For `onNavigationStateChange` prop, add below line

onNavigationStateChange={navState => {webView.current.canGoBack = navState.canGoBack}}

and in `HandleBackPressed` method check if `webView.current.canGoBack` then `webView.current.goBack();` else `return false`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import { BackHandler, Platform } from "react-native"
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-navigation"
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview"

const Webview = () => {
const webView = useRef(null);
const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', HandleBackPressed);

    return () => {
       BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', HandleBackPressed);
    }
  }
}, []); // INITIALIZE ONLY ONCE

const HandleBackPressed = () => {
    if (webView.current.canGoBack) {
        webView.current.goBack();
        return true; // PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR (EXITING THE APP)
    }
    return false;
}

return (
  <SafeAreaView>
    <WebView
      ref={webView}
      source={{
        uri: "<YOUR_URL>"
      }}
      onNavigationStateChange={navState => {webView.current.canGoBack = navState.canGoBack}} ->> This line is important
  />
 </SafeAreaView>
 )
}

export default Webview;
```

Answer (score 0):

All the functional component answers have flaws (like not being able to exit the app with back button when webview can't go back).

This behaves identically to the most upvoted class-based answer:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { BackHandler, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const App = () => {
  const webview = useRef<WebView>(null);
  const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = useState(false);

  const onAndroidBackPress = () => {
    if (canGoBack && webview.current) {
      webview.current.goBack();
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onAndroidBackPress);
    }
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onAndroidBackPress);
    }
  }, [canGoBack]);

  return (
    <WebView
      source={{uri: 'https://www.google.com'}}
      ref={webview}
      onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => setCanGoBack(navState.canGoBack)}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Functional Component, you have to use the useRef hook for hold the "canGoBack" state. Use onLoadProgress instead onNavigationStateChange, because this method works with SPA`s.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { BackHandler, NativeEventSubscription, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const Screen = () => {
  const webViewRef = useRef<WebView>(null);
  const canGoBack = useRef<boolean>(false);
  
  const onAndroidBackPress = () => {
    if (webViewRef.current && canGoBack.current) {
      webViewRef.current?.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    
    return false;
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let listener: NativeEventSubscription;
    
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      listener = BackHandler.addEventListener(
        'hardwareBackPress',
        onAndroidBackPress,
      );
    }
    
    return () => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        listener.remove();
      }
    };
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <WebView
      ref={webViewRef}
      source={{ uri: 'file:///android_asset/page.html' }}
      onLoadProgress={({ nativeEvent }) => canGoBack.current = nativeEvent.canGoBack}
    />
  );
}

export default Screen;
```