# Back button of device not working with webView

Tags: android, webview, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using wix's react-native-navigation V2 library for navigation and in one of my bottom tab i have webView. In webview i am showing website of company. following is my webview code with activity indicator.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
         onLoad={() => this.hideSpinner()}
        source={{uri: 'url'}}
        style={{marginTop: 0}}
      />
      {this.state.visible && (
          <ActivityIndicator
            style={{ position: "absolute", top: height / 2, left: width / 2 }}
            size="large"
            color="#212B51"
          />
        )}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Now the problem is when i am clicking on any link on website it going to that page but after clicking back button the app gets close not comming to previous page. i want after pressing the back button the user should go to the previous page of website.
if anyone have solution please share. Thanks in advance

Comment: you have to implement it manually, but I have no idea how to do that in react native

Comment: do anyone know how to do this

Comment: Stuck too with same problem. Please, did you finally find any solution?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39446077/react-native-go-back-on-android-hardware-back-button-pressed